# Creating Eclipse RCP application with Lars Vogel "Eclipse Products and Deployment - Tutorial"

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to create Eclipse RCP application using Eclipse 4.3.0 on Windows.

For references I took Lars Vogel article "**Eclipse Products and Deployment - Tutorial**" http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html
This tutorial doesn't give any code, but I referenced it and follow to be sure something was missed. But it was. **What went wrong?**

I create Plugin project using Multi-page Editor wizard.

I can launch from `plugin.xml` and see new plugin functionality inside Eclipse IDE runtime.

Then following the Tutorial I create .product file,
and `Application` class with generated methods (`start` and `stop`)

```
public class Application implements IApplication {
```

But when using "Launch an Eclipse application" from .product Overview, I get

```
!SESSION Fri Jan 10 13:22:34 CST 2014 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2014-01-10 13:22:34.195
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

That looks similar to old Eclipse question [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412617/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-eclipse-core-runtime-adaptor-eclipsestarte)
which is not helpful.

When using "Eclipse Product export wizard", I get files inside `eclipse` folder. But when launching my todo.exe, there is Dialog

```
Java was started but returned exit code=13
```

I have found logs in `configuration` folder

```
!SESSION Fri Jan 10 13:46:19 CST 2014 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2014-01-10 13:46:19.008
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find framework
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.getBootPath(Main.java:992)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

**What went wrong?**

I also looked at folloed story-like question [How to make simplistic RCP application really standalone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689979/how-to-make-simplistic-rcp-application-really-standalone) (that is also unaswered),
but it gave me no clues.

Finally when wrting this question, StackOverflow suggest me some similar (will look again)

- [Developing an Eclipse RCP application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239963/developing-an-eclipse-rcp-application)
- [How to create RCP plugin which is used in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702164/how-to-create-rcp-plugin-which-is-used-in-eclipse)
- [How to create an Eclipse RCP application re-using some "Eclipse IDE plugins"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562273/how-to-create-an-eclipse-rcp-application-re-using-some-eclipse-ide-plugins)

Comment: Could you share link to other Eclipse RCP tutorial that is not old.

Comment: I don't think there are any new tutorials on the 3.x style RCP as the basics have not changed for some time.

Comment: I would prefer 4.x, or any working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way to see the setup of a RCP project is to use one of the examples provided by the `New > Plug-in Project` wizard.

On the second page of the wizard select `This plug-in will make contributions to the UI` and also `Yes` for `Would you like to create a 3.x rich client application`.

With these settings the third page of the wizard should offer three RCP examples.

Note: This creates the old style 3.x RCP as covered by the tutorials you mention, there is also the new `e4` style RCP. e4 RCPs have restrictions on what existing Eclipse code you can use but have other advantages (covered in detail [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html)).

Comment: That is exactly what I had on my mind: create plugin with wizard (not following any tutorial).

I know that "Yes" is only for 3.x apps, but I am aiming at Eclipse Kepler as target version. So I did not selected it.

The link you gave is also by article by Lars Vogel that does not cover release/deployment, i.e. making executable. The is in question is actually continuation
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html But no luck so far.

Comment: You can use Kepler to produce 3.x apps, the choice is really are the restrictions on what you can use in an e4 app OK for you. The product export is the same for either style app. Creating an e4 application is different, see section 4 of the [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#tutorial_e4wizard) I linked.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

Go to run configuration of your product. Go to **Plugins** tab then click on **"Add required plugins"**. Then run your product.

### Edit:

Click on Run -> Run Configurations. See below

[image]

Comment: There is button "Add required plugins" on Dependencies Tab only, and it is disabled. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Modifying Run Configurations saved launch problem. (Please note that StackOverflow does not notify on answer edit, I wish I looked at this question sooner)

Comment: I still cannot run from Overview Tab, but only pressing the "Add Required Plugins" each time, then run. There is also miracle why there are 68 plugins to be added.